# Log all Operations of MongoDB 3.6 on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb

I want to see ALL queries which are processed by my local MongoDB instance.

I tried to set `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` but I still only get access information, but no queries.

Does anybody now how I can log EVERY query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.setProfilingLevel(2)` causes the MongoDB profiler to collect data for **all** operations.

Perhaps you are expecting the profiler docs to turn up in the MongoDB server logs? If so, then bear in mind that the profiler output is written to the `system.profile` collection in whichever database profiling has been enabled.

More details in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) but the short summary is:

```
// turn up the logging
db.setProfilingLevel(2)

// ... run some commands

// find all profiler documents, most recent first
db.system.profile.find().sort( { ts : -1 } )

// turn down the logging
db.setProfilingLevel(0)
```